# Why is credentialprovider.vss.exe going so slowly?

Tags: nuget, azure-devops, azure-artifacts

One of my build system users is having trouble getting NuGet packages from our VSTS feed. She's seeing lots of timeouts.

I've narrowed the problem to `credentialprovider.vss.exe` taking a very long time to get a credential.

On my machine, it takes ~8 seconds. On her machine it takes as much as 100 seconds on the same feed.

What might cause `credentialprovider.vss.exe` to move so slowly?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to determine what is taking so long is probably to use a tool like Fiddler to capture the HTTPS traffic. Just remember to enable the HTTPS capture in fiddler.

I'd capture your logon traffic and your co-worker's traffic, then compare the two. There will probably be something obviously different.